# Why TextInputEditText cannot be cast to TextInputLayout in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

So basically I'm getting a casting error, I tried to bind the ids with the same kind of widgets and class names.In the java file I already declared the variables with TextInputEditText instead of TextInputLayout and casted with TextInputEditText but It doesn't seem to work.Anyways, This is my activity code :

```
public class Match extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextInputEditText nomstade,prix,date,nbreplace;
    Button submitbutton;
    DatabaseReference matchDBRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.creatematch);
        nomstade =  (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.nomstade);
        prix =(TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.prix);
        submitbutton=findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
        matchDBRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Matchs");
        submitbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                insertMatchData();

            }
        });

    }
    private void insertMatchData(){
        String Stade= nomstade.getText().toString();
        String Prix= prix.getText().toString();
      

        Matchs matchs= new Matchs(Stade,Prix);
matchDBRef.push().setValue(matchs);
        Toast.makeText(Match.this,"Match created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Its corresponding XML code is:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/nomstade"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:hint="Nom du stade"
        app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="16dp"
        app:hintTextColor="#56E07B"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        tools:ignore="DuplicateIds">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/nbreplace"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:hint="Nombre de place"
        app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="16dp"
        app:hintTextColor="#56E07B"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nomstade">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

So basically when I run this code I get this error **java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText**

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That is because they are different items with different types. You can't cast the Layout type to the EditText type. If you want the `TextInputEditText` you should assign an ID to the `TextInputEditText` and find that instead of the layout parent ID.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/nbreplace"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:hint="Nombre de place"
    app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="16dp"
    app:hintTextColor="#56E07B"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nomstade">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/nbreplace_text
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Then you could do

```
nbreplace = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.nbreplace_text)
```